# How do I add Markdown formatting in a code / pre block?

Tags: formatting, markdown

This may seem to defeat the purpose of a code block, but I'd like to be able to bold something within a code block. For example, if I wanted to bold the return line:

```
int main(void) {
    **return 0;**
}
```

Comment: There is a similar question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You would have to do this in HTML,
[by design](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

> However, inside Markdown code spans and blocks, angle brackets and ampersands
>   are always encoded automatically.

```htm
<pre>
int main(void) {
    <b>return 0;</b>
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Its worth noting (because this is initially really annoying) that the reason this is by-design is because the code block could contain any code (including html) so any symbol used to denote bold inside a code block could clash with the code you're trying to type

Comment: @RichardTingle, Well, it's possible to do it if they want to. E.g. using another set of chars to escape it. e.g. "`\`\`\`\`\`\``".

Comment: Note: You cannot use `<pre lang="...">` AND `<b>`. The syntax highlighting will take precedence!

Comment: Is there any way to use `<pre>` so it behaves like a text surrounded by a pair of backticks? `like this` instead of creating a newline like triple backtick

EDIT: use <code>

Answer (score 4):

This syntax should solve your problem :

````
    ```
    int main(void) {
       **return 0;**
    }
    ```
````

Just type three backticks in the beginning of the code block and it's should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what he was doing. He was not asking how to add a code block, he was asking how to format text within the code block (in this case, how to make code bold). See accepted answer for the proper way to do it.