# How to make a GitHub README page display HTML code as is

Tags: html, github, code-snippets

I've got this small piece of HTML (a blockquote element containing a p and a footer) that I want to display on a GitHub README page as code. I've tried indenting it 4 spaces, but then it just displays what's inside the HTML, not the entire markup snippet. I also tried wrapping it around in pre and code tags and quoting it with (```). No avail.

I've used 4-space indenting in a different README so I'm really puzzled why it doesn't work this time around.

Comment: Does the file have the `.md` markdown extension?

Comment: It has a .markdown extension - I thought this was equivalent?

Comment: I don't know if it's equivalent--but you can find out by trying both to see what happens.

Comment: Tried it - doesn't work.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063896/how-do-i-add-markdown-formatting-in-a-code-pre-block/10424100#10424100 help?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do something different.

Comment: blockquote and pre doesn't work for html |   


 ```html does

Answer (score 1):

It should be `README.md`

Example

```
I've got this small piece of HTML 

<blockquote>
    <p>
    </p>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: It still shows what's inside that piece of HTML, not the markup itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding a tag by typing `<tag>` inside your markdown file. Instead, type this `&lt;tag&gt;`. Hope it works.